# Creating a ggplot where the color of point/line is dependent on the value in another column? Multiple color categories

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a set of data like below. What I want to do is plot date vs values and then have the color of the point/line depend on the X value.

I want to be able to create categories of different colors. So for example the data below, I have plotted date vs time then I would like colour to be dependent on the X value i.e., anything under 3 to display BLUE, anything above 3 and below 6 to be RED and anything above 6 to be GREEN.

I know how to create a graph which changes the color once depending on the limit I set using the code below but want to create colour categories based on the X value and also decide what colours they are.

```
    date       values       X
2021-08-09       1          0.5
2021-08-09       8          0.7
2021-08-09       6          2
2021-08-09       14         3
2021-08-09       18         5
2021-08-09       10         6
2021-08-09       1          4
2021-08-09       3          9
2021-08-09       6          0.3
2021-08-09       8          0.9
2021-08-09       11         4


    ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x = date, y = values, colour = X > 5))
```

Code now looks like this? Why is no category for 10+ showing up on the graph even though there are values of X = 10

```
    All_Hourly_1 %>%
  mutate(group = case_when(
    max_AQHI < 2 ~ 1,
    max_AQHI < 3 ~ 2,
    max_AQHI < 4 ~ 3,
    max_AQHI < 5 ~ 4,
    max_AQHI < 6 ~ 5,
    max_AQHI < 7 ~ 6,
    max_AQHI < 8 ~ 7,
    max_AQHI < 9 ~ 8,
    max_AQHI < 10 ~ 9,
    TRUE ~ 10)) %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = date, y = PM_RAMP, color = as.factor(group), group = 1)) +
  geom_line() + scale_color_manual(values = c("deepskyblue1", "dodgerblue", "dodgerblue4", "yellow", "gold", "goldenrod", "lightcoral","red", "red3", "red4"), labels = c("1 (Low Risk)","2 (Low Risk)","3 (Low Risk)","4 (Moderate Risk)","5 (Moderate Risk)","6 (Moderate Risk)","7 (High Risk)","8 (High Risk)","9 (High Risk)","10+ (Very High Risk)")) + labs(colour = "Air Quality Health Index Value") + geom_line(size = 1) + labs (x = "Date", y = expression(PM[2.5]," (µg ", m^-3,")"))
```

But the graph looks like below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try `case_when` before `ggplot` and then use `scale_color_manual` to set colors and it's better to change `date` as date format using `as.Date`.

```
df %>%
  mutate(group = case_when(
    X < 3 ~ 1,
    X < 6 ~ 2,
    TRUE ~ 3
  ), date = as.Date(date)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = values, color = as.factor(group))) +
  geom_line() + scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "green"))
```

Comment: What does the true accomplish? I am having trouble getting the top category to show i.e., X = 9

Comment: @James `case_when` is like `if` `else if` `else`. `TRUE` means `X>=6`

Comment: It still wont include the category of X = 9 in the legend for the plot even when i include that

Comment: @James I'm sorry that I cannot understand your problem. What I understood is that `x<3` and `3<= x <6` and `6<x` are each categories. `X = 9` are the last category with color green. In my code, `x<3` is `group 1` and `3~6` is `group 2` and `6~` is `group 3`.

Comment: Have edited it and hopefully gives you better idea. I have no category showing u for "10 (Very High Risk"). I have tried using drop = FALSE. But the data (x values) does have a few values that are equal to 10.0000

Comment: @James In this case I might need to look up to your data. I'm not sure why there isn't very high risk exists.

Answer (score 1):

### Data

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("2021-08-09", "2021-08-10", "2021-08-11", 
"2021-08-12", "2021-08-13", "2021-08-14", "2021-08-15", "2021-08-16", 
"2021-08-17", "2021-08-18", "2021-08-19"), values = c(1L, 8L, 
6L, 14L, 18L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 11L), X = c(0.5, 0.7, 2, 3, 
5, 6, 4, 9, 0.3, 0.9, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

### How to

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(color = cut(X,c(0,2,5,Inf),labels = c("<3","<6","6+"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = values, color = color, group = 1)) +
  geom_line()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "green"))
```

### Result

[image]